# include header file out of themes folder wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, include, themes

I have a file order.php exist at "website/order.php".

**Question**

I want to include header.php file into order.php file that exist at website/wp-content/themes/template/header.php . I am using this code in order.php file, but it is not working

```
include('wp-content/themes/business/header.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write below code:

```
include "wp-load.php";
 get_header();
```